# How can I create an animated .gif from a movie?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, quicktime, gif

How can I create an animated .gif file from a movie I have?
I guess it is pretty simple in objective-C and cocoa, by using the QTKit, to extract images from a movie, now how can I glue them together as an animated gif?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a pretty good lib (even if 'old') for this task (and other kinds of image processing): [libgd](http://www.libgd.org/Main_Page). It appears it is built into Mac OS X or easly installable through [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/). Here some doc [about animated GIF creation from single images](http://www.libgd.org/ImageCreation#void_gdImageGifAnimBegin.28gdImagePtr_im.2C_FILE_.2Aout.2C_int_GlobalCM.2C_int_Loops.29).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's anything built into OS X for creating animated GIFs.  Your best bet would be to look at the gifsicle project. You could either call it via command-line, or borrow the code if your license allows it. (it's GPL)

http://www.lcdf.org/gifsicle/

Comment: Thank you for your response, I'll have a look at it. But it seems it'll have to carve a lib up from it : D

Comment: I started to have a look at libgd, as stated in another answer.